# IF condition using string

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am programming in Polymer 1.0 and am trying to create an IF function to change the value of a property. My function is the following:

```
_searchButton: function(selectednamedropdown, selectedtypedropdown){
  if (selectednamedropdown=="no_name_selected" && selectedtypedropdown=="no_type_selected"){
    this.searchUsagesBtn = true
  } else{
    this.searchUsagesBtn = false
  }
}
```

In my mind when selectednamedropdown is equal to "no_name_selected" and selectedtypedropdown is equal to "no_type_selected" the function should set searchUsagesBtn to true and when they are not these values, false.

However, the function does not ever seem to be returning true even when these conditions are met. Any ideas why this might be? Thanks for all help

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the function to see if `selectednamedropdown` and `selectedtypedropdown` are really what you think they are?

Comment: I have - as I am using polymer I can see the data bind and have displayed these to confirm they are are in fact the strings they should be

Comment: I have also put a console.log in work out which situation is firing and it seems false is firing every time even when the true conditions are met

Comment: I think you are having the problem with the scope of `this`, thinking from a vanilla JS perspective.

Comment: Clearly the condition is not being met, because if it was the block in the if statement would run. I would put a console.log at the beginning of your function to find out what the value of both variables are. Or setting a break point like Matt said

Comment: I can see the values being parsed in and I can see they do meet those conditions

Comment: 1) If you put a `console.log(selectednamedropdown)` and a `console.log(selectedtypedropdown)` at the top of your function, what does it actually say? (not what do you think it says). 2) Does the line `this.searchUsagesBtn = true` ever actually get reached? If you put a breakpoint or a `console.log` there does it get hit? 3) What do you get if you `console.log(this)`? Is it what you expected? Since `if` most certainly isn't broken in Javascript, your problem is somewhere else with your logic. With out more info, my guess would be that `selectednamedropdown` is an object, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was around how JavaScript treats properties within functions. The function was storing the new value and old value of the first property and not any values of the second property. The solution involved making 2 functions to test the strings in each property. Thanks for all assistance

Comment: It sounds a bit strange.. and not related to JavaScript itself.. maybe you mean that your method was a simple observer over the first property instead of being a complex observer over both of them..

Answer (score 1):

When I run your function like this:

```
    let searchUsagesBtn;
function search(selectednamedropdown, selectedtypedropdown) {
  if (
    selectednamedropdown === "no_name_selected" &&
    selectedtypedropdown === "no_type_selected"
  ) {
    searchUsagesBtn = true;
  } else {
    searchUsagesBtn = false;
  }
}

search("no_name_selected", "no_type_selected");
console.log("button: ", searchUsagesBtn);
```

I get `button: true` in console log. So maybe your inputs in this function are not a strings.

Comment: the inputs are attributes within my template - they are actually on a component called a paper listbox and I have defined them within the html tags as selectednamedropdown="no_type_selected" so I believe these are stored as strings